# How to install XNA in Visual Studio 2015 (Preview)

Tags: xna, visual-studio-2015

How can I install the templates and the the framework for XNA in Visual Studio 2015?

I found [this page here](https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases) that helps installing the XNA framework in Visual Studio 2013, but they do not offer any downloads for Visual Studio 2015.

I know that XNA is not developed anymore by Microsoft, but it is a really great Framework that I need to use in Future.

Comment: Worth noting, since posting your question, the link in your question has updated to include VS2015.

Comment: And now what? Do you want to remove the question then?

Comment: No. It is simply good information to have for future readers of the question, and not worth a full answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

XNA 4.0 Refresh Now fully supports Visual Studio 2015.

You can find the download for XNA 4.0 Refresh here: https://mxa.codeplex.com/releases/view/618279

It's a zip which contains a Visual Studio extension and various prerequisites. The prerequisites should be installed first, in the order stated in `README.txt`:

1. DirectX
2. XNA Framework 4.0 Redistribution
3. XNA Game Studio 4.0 Platform Tools
4. XNA Game Studio 4.0 Shared

Answer (score 25):

EDIT: This one is obsolete; please see Lee Stott's answer above!

I used the XNA Refresh package that can be [downloaded here](https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases/view/117230) and did all the steps exactely as for VS 2013. But I edited the .vsix file because it doesn't let you install it in VS 2015. It turns out it is simply a ZIP-File. I fixed the version numbers in **extension.vsixmanifest** to 14.0.

```
<Installation InstalledByMsi="false">
  <InstallationTarget Version="14.0" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSWinDesktopExpress" />
  <InstallationTarget Version="14.0" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />
  <InstallationTarget Version="14.0" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium" />
  <InstallationTarget Version="14.0" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate" />
</Installation>
```

This lets you install the vsix package in Visual Studio 2015!

Comment: Good job! After doing so, does it work correctly? Did you try all templates? If it does, I'll be doing it myself :)

Comment: I had no problems, custom pipelines, sounds and 3d modles work correctly. But one big problem: compiling always takes about a minute. That is not normal.

Comment: While trying to make Windows Phone Game, I am encountering following error: 

Your installation of XNA Game Studio does not support this project (XNA Platform = 'Windows Phone', XNA Framework Version = 'v4.0').

Comment: I didnt test other platforms that for windows! Maybe you try MonoGame?

Comment: This helped me out with the CRM UII VSIX package as well. Thanks. +1

Comment: Does Community let you install other .vsix files? If yes, these steps should work

Answer (score 9):

Works fine with Visual Studio 2015 :

1- Download the latest version of this package
https://mxa.codeplex.com/releases

2- Unzip the content

3- Follow the readme and install all files except the 'vsix'

3- Open the 'XNA Game Studio 4.0.vsix' with the Windows zip

4- Replace code of the 'extension.vsixmanifest' (opened by text editor) file by the following one. Save it on your desktop.

5- Copy the modified 'extension.vsixmanifest' into 'XNA Game Studio 4.0.vsix'

6- Run the vsix with Visual Studio !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Vsix xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2010">
<Identifier Id="bcc70cc4-703d-4f8b-98f5-d96bfc71335b">
<Name>XNA Game Studio 4.0</Name>
<Author>Microsoft</Author>
<Version>1.4.12</Version>
<Description xml:space="preserve">XNA Game Studio Package provides game development experiences for Xbox 360, Windows, and Windows Phone.</Description>
<Locale>1033</Locale>
<Icon>Package.ico</Icon>
<InstalledByMsi>false</InstalledByMsi>
<SupportedProducts>
  <VisualStudio Version="10.0">
    <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
    <Edition>Premium</Edition>
    <Edition>Pro</Edition>
    <Edition>IntegratedShell</Edition>
  </VisualStudio>
  <VisualStudio Version="11.0">
    <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
    <Edition>Premium</Edition>
    <Edition>Pro</Edition>
    <Edition>IntegratedShell</Edition>
    <Edition>VSLS</Edition>
  </VisualStudio>
  <VisualStudio Version="12.0">
    <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
    <Edition>Premium</Edition>
    <Edition>Pro</Edition>
    <Edition>IntegratedShell</Edition>
    <Edition>VSLS</Edition>
  </VisualStudio>
  <VisualStudio Version="14.0">
    <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
    <Edition>Premium</Edition>
    <Edition>Pro</Edition>
    <Edition>IntegratedShell</Edition>
    <Edition>VSLS</Edition>
  </VisualStudio>
</SupportedProducts>
<SupportedFrameworkRuntimeEdition MinVersion="4.0" />
</Identifier>
<References>
<Reference Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF" MinVersion="10.0">
  <Name>Visual Studio MPF</Name>
</Reference>
</References>
<Content>
<VsPackage>XNA Game Studio 4.0.pkgdef</VsPackage>
<VsPackage>Microsoft.Xna.GameStudio.Core.pkgdef</VsPackage>
<VsPackage>Microsoft.Xna.GameStudio.pkgdef</VsPackage>
<VsPackage>Microsoft.Xna.VisualBasic.PropertyPages.pkgdef</VsPackage>
<ItemTemplate>ItemTemplates</ItemTemplate>
<ProjectTemplate>ProjectTemplates</ProjectTemplate>
<Assembly AssemblyName="Microsoft.Xna.GameStudio.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d5c3888ef60e27d">Microsoft.Xna.GameStudio.Core.dll</Assembly>
<Assembly AssemblyName="Microsoft.Xna.GameStudio, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d5c3888ef60e27d">Microsoft.Xna.GameStudio.dll</Assembly>
<Assembly AssemblyName="Microsoft.Xna.VisualBasic.PropertyPages, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d5c3888ef60e27d">Microsoft.Xna.VisualBasic.PropertyPages.dll</Assembly>
</Content>
</Vsix>
```

Comment: Would be nice if you could add some explanation, too.

Comment: Edited ! I just use the same file the above answer