# No option to load a SpriteFont in XNA4 Content project with VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xna-4.0, spritefont

I can't find any option to load a new SpriteFont in the XNA Content project.

This is my screen:

[image]

I downloaded the XNA4.0 refresh update for Visual Studio 2015 from here https://mxa.codeplex.com/releases/view/618279

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I also use VS2015, I created a new XNA project myself and to my surprise it was there for me located under Visual C#

[image]

However, the other image options or 'Graphics' section you have are not listed for me. This is probably because I'm using the Community edition and I don't have the built-in editor.

During the XNA-VS2015 November release a [few](https://mxa.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced) problems were reported, but this one is not there. I remember it took me quite a while in order to get everything working. While following the instructions provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008970/how-to-install-xna-in-visual-studio-2015-preview) question, double-clicking `XNA Game Studio 4.0.vsix` did nothing for me until I finally found  out you had to specifically right-click and use it as an administrator in order to let the VSIX installer work correctly.

My suggestion would be to reinstall XNA completely and follow the XNA installation instructions again in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008970/how-to-install-xna-in-visual-studio-2015-preview) question. This will ensure that an incorrect installation is not part of the problem.

If this still doesn't fix it, reinstall VS2015 or downgrade to an older version of VS.

Comment: I'm using the Comminity edition too, and I wouldn't think about VS malfunctioning since I never had problems with it. I installed the framework extension following the readme in the ZIP archive, installing the other packages as first. I'll try to reinstall XNA

Comment: I just found, that I followed exactly that thread to install the framework, so I'm thinking of a broken XNA

Comment: That's great to hear, mark the question as resolved in order to help other people with similar problems in the future.

Comment: The installer is still repairing the framework installation, so I still don't know if that worked :(

Comment: The installer wanted me to update VS to  2015.1 (which failed), but after complete reinstallation of XNA, I found the SpriteFont entry in the C# panel, but still have the other Bitmap options in the Graphics tab.