# Can't find file XNA?

Tags: c#, file, xna

So I'm trying to load a SpriteFont in XNA using

```
Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Font");
```

And I put the .spritefont file in the content project. But when I try to run the program it says the file doesn't exist. I know this is has been asked before but nothing worked.

[EDIT] A similar thing happened too, when I tried to import a wav file using the same means, it says there is some error in the file. But it plays fine outside of Visual Studio. Also, in "Project/Bin/x86/Debug/Content" it saving the files as font_0.xnb. I know it's SUPPOSED to be .xnb, but it's supposed not have the "_0". So I think that's the problem, and if so. How do I fix it?

PLUS I tried doing the same thing in a different XNA project, the same thing happened. I reinstalled XNA as a last resort, nothing works! ARRGHH

Comment: My memory is the resources must be in a resource project.  It's been long enough since I played with XNA and I never did much with it so I'm not sure, though.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by resource project, although I probably should. And how to fix it?

Comment: I think Loren is just referring to the content project, which you mentioned using, so that aspect should be okay. What is the exact wording of the error you're getting and any codes that accompany it? Also, what is the name of the spritefont file that's in your content project in the solution explorer?

Comment: The spritefont is just called "font." I tried different names though. Also, the exact error is An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll

Additional information: Error loading "font". File not found.

Comment: Have you tried passing "font_0" as an argument in the Load<> method?

Comment: Actually, yes! It works if I

Comment: 'm trying to load a bitmap photo. But if I try a SpriteFont it saysAdditional information: Error loading "font_0". File contains Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Graphics.FontDescription but trying to load as Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteFont.

Comment: In your ProjectContent/obj/x86/Debug/ folder, there should be a file called ContentPipeline.xml. One of the Items in there should describe your font. Can you just tell me what's in those tags? (you can omit the Time)

Comment: <Source>font.spritefont</Source>
<Importer>FontDescriptionImporter</Importer>
<Options>None</Options>
<Output>C:\Users\***********\bin\x86\Debug\Content\font_0.xnb</Output>
<Time>****</Time>
</Item>

Comment: Okay try this: Open up ProjectContent.contentproj (in your ProjectContent directory) in a text editor. There should be an ItemGroup involving your font. Make sure between the Compile tags you have 
      <Name>font</Name>
      <Importer>FontDescriptionImporter</Importer>
      <Processor>FontDescriptionProcessor</Processor>. Then save it, and allow VS to reload the file and then try running.

Comment: <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="font.spritefont" ></Compile> <Name>font</Name> <Importer>FontDescriptionImporter</Importer> <Processor>FontDescriptionProcessor</Processor> />
  </ItemGroup> //Should this be it? I'm kinda confused. Also, there's an error saying: The element <#text> beneath element <ItemGroup> is unrecognized
Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: The </Compile> should be right after </Processor>

Comment: Ok,  there is still that error though.

Comment: Okay. If you highlight font.spritefont in your solution explorer, what shows up in the Properties window?

Comment: Build Action: Compile

Comment: File Name: font.spritefont, Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy.

Comment: No properties in a category "XNA Framework Content Pipeline"?

Comment: No. I need more letters to post this comment. :-)

Comment: Someone else with a similar problem reinstalled and it was fixed. Are you using XNA 4? What version of VS?

Comment: I'm using VS 2015 Community, with XNA 4.0. I tried re-installing XNA though. It didn't work. >:(

Comment: Have you ever been able to load a SpriteFont in XNA (in projects before this one)? Are you using this version of XNA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008970/how-to-install-xna-in-visual-studio-2015-preview ?

Comment: I have not been able to use SpriteFont before. I am downloading that one though.

Comment: It worked! You're REAL life saver! Anything I can do in return?

Comment: Oh good! I can post that as the answer to your question. You can mark it as the answer and upvote anything else I've said here that was helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the right version of XNA to go with your version of Visual Studio. If you have VS2015, installing this version of XNA should help: https://mxa.codeplex.com/releases/view/618279